# Assign label names for line plot from NumPy 2D array

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I want to plot a `2D` `NumPy` array using `line` plots for each of the columns:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

arr = np.random.random((10, 5))
ax.plot(arr)
```

However, I am not sure how to assign `label` names for each of the five columns.

Assume that the column names are : `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` and `e`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, there's no built-in way to pass in multiple different labels for each line in a single call to `plot`. You could loop over columns in your array and plot each one separately:

```
labels = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']

for column, label in zip(arr.T, labels):
    ax.plot(column, label=label)
```

Or you could construct your legend by passing the line objects and their corresponding labels explicitly:

```
lines = ax.plot(arr)
ax.legend(lines, labels)
```